# Modify template used by best bets

Tags: search, display-template, promoted-results, query-rule

I have set up a query rule to include a promoted result which is working fine and I see my promoted result at the top of search results for specific search terms. This is all great.

But I don't want it to use the default Best Bet search results item template. I would prefer not to change the OOTB template and would prefer to make my own, perhaps called something like `Item_MyPromotedTemplate.html`.

I know how to do that and have created it, but I don't see anyplace in SharePoint to say, hey on this site use My Promoted template instead of Best Bet.

I looked in the **Result types**. I see my custom template, but I'm not seeing how to say, "Use this for best bet/promoted results."

I've tried searching the web for tutorials, but all I can find are [results like this](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.in/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-search-modifying.html) which show how to modify the existing `Item_BestBet.html` template. And I don't really want to change the default template.

Is there some way to use a custom item template for best bet/promoted results?

Answer (score 0):

make a copy of existing and create a new one pointing to modified best bets display template. Now deactivate the original.

Comment: Can you explain where you can deactivate the original?

Comment: Can you explain how to point to the modified one? That is kind of my question.

Comment: sorry, there is nothing like deactivate, just use the priority dropdown on the left to push your new result types to top